# Cuál es el mejor tipo de dato para almacenar nombres, direcciones, entre otros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy aprendiendo sobre SQL y me ha surgido una duda, en búsqueda de tener creados de manera correcta los tipos de dato.

Me gustaría saber que tipo de dato recomiendan para almacenar:

- Nombres
- Direcciones
- Teléfonos
- Correos Electrónicos
- Fechas
- Imágenes
- Números enteros
- Números con decimal

Si tienen algún artículo que hable de esto, también estaría agradecido.

Comment: En realidad yo recomiendo más el uso de varchar que de String, aquí te dejo algo de documentación, tiene muy buena información, espero y te sirva. [SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según mi experiencia y limitándome al listado que diste serían de la siguiente forma:

> - Nombres -> Varchar(longitud)
> - Direcciones -> Varchar(longitud)
> - Teléfonos -> Varchar o Int, aunque en realidad setear un teléfono como número es un tanto innecesario ya que nunca usarás una operación
>     matemática (me refiero a sumar, restar, etc) con un teléfono.
> - Correos -> Varchar(longitud)
> - Fechas -> Date o Datetime, dependiendo lo que requieras y la versión de SQL que estés utilizando.
> - Imágenes -> Varchar(longitud)
> - Números enteros -> Int o BigInt dependiendo el límite del número a ingresar.
> - Números con decimal -> Decimal

**Podría ser útil también el tipo `BIT` que funciona como un `true/false`, aunque en la base se almacena como `0` y `1`.**

Los tipos de datos que específique estan pensados para SQL 2008, creo que añadieron más tipo de datos para versiones posteriores pero ignoro cuales son.

Te dejo el artículo **[Tipos de datos (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** (en español) para que te interiorices más

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, Paulo

Answer (score -1):

Creo que tu pregunta es por el lado de la BD mas no por el lenguaje, por ende seria lo recomendado asi:

1. Nombres nvarchar (cant)
2. Direcciones nvarchar (cant)
3. Teléfonos nvarchar (cant)
4. Correos Electrónicos nvarchar (cant)
5. Fechas date()
6. Imágenes nvarchar (Si le pasas una URL)
7. Imágenes binary(Si le pasas una URL)
8. Números enteros int(cant)
9. Números con decimal decimal()

> // con los numero, solo si vas a hacer operaciones matematicas es
>   recomendable ponerlos en tipo int de lo contrario en char

Espero que te servir !, me cunetas...

Comment: Fechas puede ser igual un `DateTime`, números con decimal depende, puede ser un `float`, `double` o incluso `money`

Comment: @Phi, si es verdad, solo que pues solo pongo lo que mas comunes, ya que el dice pueden ser, pues estos otros tipo los usamamos cuando necesitamos hacer cierto tipo de operaciones en el sistema, de igual forma es correcto lo que dices...

Comment: En realidad esta pregunta debería ser cerrada por estar basada en opiniones, a menos que el usuario ponga datos exactos y con base en eso poner qué tipos de dato exacto puede usar

Answer (score -1):

En SQL en general, para los nombres, direcciones, teléfonos, correos electrónicos yo usaría String o VARCHAR. Omitiendo lo obvio como en nombres y direcciones, el caso de los teléfonos siempre hay personas que diseñan sus bases de datos con NUMERIC o INT pero siempre existe el problema con los teléfonos con ceros al inicio e inclusive con números de identificación (DNI o cedula). Para el caso de los emails o correos electrónicos te recomiendo VARCHAR de igual manera que con los nombres o direcciones, controlando el registro de que sean solo emails, desde tu aplicación o programa, y no desde tu BD, es una tarea menos para la BD y la aplicación o programa la puede controlar desde que se registra en el formulario.

Para el caso de las fechas a menos que necesites enteramente la fecha con hora utiliza DATETIME pero si solo es necesario para tu registro en BD la fecha utiliza tipo DATE. Manejar luego consultas en SQL con datos tipo DATETIME es complicado y necesitas siempre convertidores o parsear la data en tu programa.

Esto en base a la experiencia. Saludos

Answer (score -2):

Si el motor de base de datos que se vaya a utilizar tiene un tipo de dato nativo para almacenar fechas, usarlo para almacenar las fechas.

Hay que determinar si para ese motor de base de datos las fechas son solo el año-mes-día o si se incluye el componente de **hora-minuto-segundo**.

Es importante anotar que una cosa es cómo una base de datos almacena un valor de tipo `FECHA` y otra muy diferente como se visualiza en pantalla o se imprime esa fecha.

En el caso de `Oracle`, (`SQL y el lenguage PL/SQL`) existe el tipo de dato `DATE` (tanto para columnas como para variables) con el cual se almacena una fecha con la **hora-minuto-segundo**.

El usar un tipo de dato "`STRING`" para almacenar y manejar fechas es inconveniente  ya que existen un sinúmero de maneras de escribir una cadena (o string) que represente una fecha, que depende fundamentalmente del país y y con los cuales se producen errores al momento de ordenar, buscar y comparar fechas.

Ejemplo: 
Si una fecha es **10 de agosto de 2018**, entonces hay estas alternativas:

> - Para Estados Unidos y otros países es "**08/10/2018**" (el mes primero)
> - En Europa es común escribirla como "**10/08/2018**"    (el día primero)
> - O escribir el mes con un texto como "**30-agosto-2018**"

Ejemplo de error al usar strings para representar una fecha:
Si hay 2 cadenas que representan una fecha almacenada como día/mes/año:

> - "**04/01/2017**" (para el 04 de enero de 2017)
>
>   - "**03/02/2018**" (para el 03 de marzo de 2018)

Se hace una comparación de los 2 strings y cuál será menor?
La respuesta es que por comparación de strings el menor es "**03/02/2018**" lo cual es errado!! ya que desde el punto de vista que el string representa una fecha la cual es **MAYOR** que la fecha "**04/01/2017**".

Si definitivamente hay que usar texto (o strings) para almacenar una fecha la recomendación es usar la norma [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), con la cual el string SIEMPRE es:

> Para año-mes-dia es "AAAAMMDD" o "AAAA-MM-DD"      y con
>   hora-minuto-segundo es "AAAAMMDDTHHMMSS" ó "AAAA-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" ó
>   "AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

```
Los años son de 4 dígitos   
Los meses son de 2 dígitos, de 01 al 12  
Los días son de 2 dígitos, de 01 al último día correspondiente mes (28,29, 30,31).  
Las horas son en formato militar de las 00 a las 23  
Los minutos son de 2 dígitos, de 00 al 59  
Los segundos son de 2 dígitos, del 00 al 59
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @alvalongo Realmente profundizaste en tu respuesta, la tome mucho en cuenta para mi estudio.

Answer (score -5):

Según yo utilizo esos datos, los defino de la siguiente forma:

- Nombres (string)
- Direcciones (string)
- Teléfonos (string)
- Correos Electrónicos (string)
- Fechas (string)
- Imágenes (string (Si le pasas una URL))
- Números enteros (int)
- Números con decimal (float)

Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda!

Comment: Sólo difiero en el decimal, para esos existe el campo DECIMAL en Sql Server, y para fechas el DATE ó DATETIME

Comment: Para números con decimal depende, si son cantidades monetarias existe un tipo de dato `Money`

Comment: Es cierto, que hay varias posibilidades para un mismo tipo de campo, el que más te convenga o guste, no debería haber problema.

Comment: ¿String? Me parece que ningún tipo de dato se llama *string*. ¿Habrás querido decir `VARCHAR` o `CHAR` o alguno parecido? Y... ¿por qué no recomiendas `DATETIME` para los campos con fecha? Me parece que tu respuesta desorienta al OP.

Comment: La costumbre de llamarlo String, Cierto, que me refería al tipo VARCHAR, en cuanto al campo DATETIME, He preferido recomendar VARCHAR, debido a que me ha dado (personalmente) menos problemas a la hora de trabajar fechas, eso sí, de forma sencilla.

Comment: ¿Cómo va a ser que trabajar un campo de tipo fecha como cadena te va a dar menos problemas?  Eso es totalmente imposible. Un campo de tipo cadena te permitiría fechas así por ejemplo: `40-40-2018` ¿cómo controlas que no existe un día `40` ni un mes `40`?  Y cuando haya que calcular con fechas te quiero ver. Si quieres saber cuántos días han pasado entre el valor de la columna y la fecha actual tendrás entonces que convertir la cadena a fecha (lo que debió ser desde el principio)  para poder hacer el cálculo. Los tipos de datos existen por algo, nunca deberías usar un tipo de dato equivocado.